# Chrome not play html5 video on duplicated tags

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

On my page i have two video tags vith same video source.
Example:

```
<video id="video_description_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" poster="poster.jpg" preload="metadata">
<source src="video.mp4.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="video.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.mp4.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<video id="video_preview" class="vjs-tech" poster="poster.jpg" preload="metadata">
<source src="video.mp4.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="video.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.mp4.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

When i start to play one of these videos in Google Chrome and then try to play second - last one not loading.
this bug/feature only in chrome. firefox play both video at the same time correctly.

Any idea how can i force to play second video?

Comment: I don't have something convenient to test with, but try adding ?1 to the video URLs:
`<source src="video.mp4.ogv?1" type="video/ogg">
<source src="video.mp4.mp4?1" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.mp4.webm?1" type="video/webm">`
The downside is that the videos will have to be loaded twice, so this isn't ideal... I'm assuming there's a bug with chrome keeping it from playing the same source on the same page twice, btw. I didn't notice any problems with your code.

Comment: cool.. it work for me. tank you.

Comment: Great! Just keep in mind, chrome will load the video files twice into memory, and twice from the server, using this method. However, I'm not sure there's a good alternative until Chrome fixes this bug.

Comment: Maybe having two preloads cause an issue?  Have you tried removing the second preload?

Comment: i tried remove all preloads for both video tags. when first loading the second can not start preload. but when first finished play video , second can load and play.

Comment: try this document.getElementById('video_preview').play()

Answer (score 0):

(Commenter @Hamza Kubba came up with the answer that original poster reports solved the problem for them, but it's in the comments. Copying/pasting here as an answer, where it belongs.)

> ...try adding ?1 to the video URLs: `<source src="video.mp4.ogv?1" type="video/ogg"> <source src="video.mp4.mp4?1" type="video/mp4"> <source src="video.mp4.webm?1" type="video/webm">` The downside is that the videos will have to be loaded twice, so this isn't ideal... I'm assuming there's a bug with chrome keeping it from playing the same source on the same page twice, btw. I didn't notice any problems with your code.
>
> ...keep in mind, chrome will load the video files twice into memory, and twice from the server, using this method. However, I'm not sure there's a good alternative until Chrome fixes this bug.